# Pure css parallax scrolling image doesn't fill up page

Tags: html, css, pure-css-parallax

I want the image take up the whole page. Right now there's a big space under the image. Changing the transform, position and size properties doesn't affect the empty space's size.

HTML:

```
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layoutindex.css" type="text/css"></link>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/941/thumb-1920-941898.jpg" class="background">
      </header>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    perspective: 10px;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    z-index: -1;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100vw;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: translateZ(-10px) scale(2);
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried [this code](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code does exactly what you want - [Codepen](https://codepen.io/thejamel/pen/YzadNox). I am assuming there is additonal code on your site?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify, the image is supposed to slide slower than everything else as you scroll and if you scroll to the bottom of the page there is a space between the image's and the page's end.